# How to get data from Dyn365 into Excel

Tags: excel, api, dynamics-crm

I am trying to automate the task in the subject line. I have a custom view in my CRM that gives me the data I need (purchase order records). My plan was to export it out as a dynamic worksheet so that I could simply refresh the embedded query within the worksheet when needed. Problem is - the query doesn't refresh - I am quite sure it's for the reasons described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2556284/after-exporting-microsoft-dynamics-crm-dynamic-worksheets-and-or-dynam). The resolution offered in the article does not work for me - I am unable to install the Dyn365 for Outlook - getting the following error:

> There are no eligible environments to install this app. To install an
> app, you must have a successfully provisioned environment in the
> region where the application is available and the environment must
> have a database connection.

The workaround described in the article doesn't work for me either.

I tried Power Querying the SSAS database that I know is linked to our CRM, but some of the data points I need are not in it. Plus, it looks like it only refreshes once a day. Not sure if another database with a real-time refresh exists, or, if it does, whether I'll be granted access, so just trying other options for now.

At the moment, I am exporting the Excel file from CRM "front end" with a bit of IE automation - not ideal, but works for me. However, eventually I will need to share this solution with other people in the company and I'd like to avoid having to explain how "it's going to open an invisible browser window, log in as you and download a file" - this would raise a few eyebrows for sure.

Question - what other options do I have here? Is it possible to get this data via an API call perhaps? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that I can add "/api/data/v8.2" after the crm URL and use that new URL to import the data into Excel (Get Data / From Online Services / From Dynamics 365 online).